# Copying a temp file

Tags: java

I have tried searching for the answer this problem but have not found it exactly. I am trying to determine how to make a hard copy of a temp file. All my searching only showed how to copy a standard file.

My program allows the user to upload a file. This file is then read and analyzed and a new temp file is created and written to.

Next I want to copy the temp file to an actual hard location depending on a user selection.

The reason I am doing it like this is that the actual program I am writing used to have the user upload a file and select the save destination during the beginning but I have been asked to make the program only ask for the save destination in the very end. This is why I need a temp file to hold the data until the end of the program when the user is asked for the destination.

Note that this code sets the destination:

```
while(saveApproval==false){//While the user does not have approval of the save location..


        JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new JFileChooser object.

        saveFile = chooser2;//Sets the save file location to chooser2. 

        chooser2.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);//User is only able to scan for 
        //directories. 

        //Completes once the user clicks okay. 
        int returnValue2 = chooser2.showDialog(chooser2, "Directory to save");
        if(returnValue2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            saveApproval=true;
        }else{
            System.exit(0);
        }

        }
```

So I want to take the File variable nachaFile and copy the temp data into it. I then want to save nachaFile into the saveFile variable directory the user has selected. Below you will find my complete sample code I have created:

```
package testingtemp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class MainClass 

{

    public static JFileChooser uploadFile;
    public static JFileChooser saveFile;
    public static boolean uploadApproval;
    public static boolean saveApproval;
    public static File temp;
    public static File nachaFile;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        while(uploadApproval==false){//While upload approval has not been given..

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new object of the JFileChooser class. 

            uploadFile = chooser;//Saves the upload file variable as the chooser response. 

            chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");//Sets the title bar text. 

            //Completes once the user clicks ok. 
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);//
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                uploadApproval=true;
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }

            try{

                File temp = File.createTempFile("NachaTemp", ".ach");

            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try{

            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uploadFile.getSelectedFile()));



            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

            String line;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

                writer.write("1");

            }

            while(saveApproval==false){//While the user does not have approval of the save location..

                JFileChooser chooser2 = new JFileChooser();//Creates a new JFileChooser object.

                saveFile = chooser2;//Sets the save file location to chooser2. 

                chooser2.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);//User is only able to scan for 
                //directories. 

                //Completes once the user clicks okay. 
                int returnValue2 = chooser2.showDialog(chooser2, "Directory to save");
                if(returnValue2 == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                    saveApproval=true;
                }else{
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                }


        }catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally{

            try{

                reader.close();
                writer.close();

            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    }

Files.copy(temp, saveFile.getSelectedFile()+"THISISATEST.ACH");


}

}
```

Comment: Could you make Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? What you have posted is very hard to read and there is not any wish to try understand it

Comment: I believe the above meets all those except complete. I can't have a complete example because I don't yet know how to do what I'm asking. 

Somewhere at the end of that code I want to copy the temp file with a given name to the "saveFile" variable destination.

Comment: I added one more line at the bottom of the code where I try to create a copy. Please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to copy a file is to use [`Files.copy(src, dest)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

However I think you would rather [move](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) the file in your case.

Maybe even better depending on which ressources are scarse, you could also hold the data in a buffer until you get the `saveApproval`, and only then create a file at its final destination.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you mind going into a bit more detail? When you say Files.copy is the src just "temp" in the above case and the destination would be saveFile.getSelectedFiles()+"//NachaOutput.ACH"

Comment: I added one line at the bottom of my code trying the copy. It doesn't work please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @jesric1029 the `Files` methods take `Path` objects as parameters, which you can obtain from a `File` with their `toPath()` method.